# Update list of branch on readthedocs

Tags: read-the-docs

I'm probably missing something but I don't understand why my latest [PR branch](https://github.com/dadoonet/fscrawler/tree/docs) is not available in the readthedocs admin console.

I'm using Github with a Webhook. I checked that Github did call readthedocs.

```
Request URL: https://readthedocs.org/api/v2/webhook/fscrawler/15094/
Request method: POST
content-type: application/json
Expect: 
User-Agent: GitHub-Hookshot/a467b7d
X-GitHub-Delivery: c765fa80-7133-11e8-9ba2-7420dc4cec22
X-GitHub-Event: push
```

The response I got is:

```
{"project":"fscrawler","build_triggered":false,"versions":[]}
```

I guess this is because I did not set this branch to active in the readthedocs console?

So I tried to activate it manually. But I can't see the `docs` branch in my readthedocs console. Is there a way to trigger a refresh of the list of the github branches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I missed the option in the `Versions` tab.
I was able to see my branch there and I just had to set it active.

Not sure how I missed it. May it's a new feature???